# How to execute a function instead insert into table in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use this SQL code to detect which table should use for insert

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION detect_table() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
 IF ( NEW.ip = '192.168.1.1') THEN INSERT INTO child_table_one VALUES (NEW.*);
 ELSIF ( NEW.ip = '192.168.1.100') THEN INSERT INTO child_table_two VALUES (NEW.*);
 ELSE RAISE EXCEPTION 'IP not correct ';
 END IF;
 RETURN NULL;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

with this trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON parent_table
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE detect_table();
```

but this query insert in both parent and child table.

```
INSERT INTO parent_table VALUES('192.168.1.1', 'other data')
```

How to insert record only into child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. there is no problem in these queries the problem was on my SELECT. I should select only from parent_table.

```
SELECT * FROM ONLY parent_table
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM parent_table
```

shows nothing in  my parent table.